# Producing Index

Tags: indexing

I have been trying to produce an index with a lot of difficulty.

I have followed the guides provided...especially

> To produce the index you need:
>   `\usepackage{makeidx}` and `\makeindex` in the preamble
>   a `\printindex` where you want the index to appear, and,
>   you need to run `makeindex` on the `.idx` file that LaTeX produces.

My current confusion is the last line above. I can see the `.idx` file output after

`\usepackage{makeidx}` and `\makeindex` in the preamble
a `\printindex`

but I do not understand how to run the `makeindex` on it...in simple terms.

One suggestion says, run `pdflatex`, then run `MakeIndex` and the run `pdflatex` again.

This hasn't worked for me.

Kindly guide is simple steps.

Thanks

Comment: How to 'ru `makeindex`' might depend on the editor you use. Some of them come with a accordingly named button that you can press to run the program. Independant from the editor, you should be able to use `makeindex filename.idx` (wifht 'filename'  being the name of your corresponding `.tex`file) in your command line

Comment: There is now an alternative packaga `imakeidx` that under many circumstances will process and include the index in the first pass.  This does partly depend on the LaTeX system you use.

Comment: I use Tex Live 2017, the editor is TeXworks editor. But I am entirely new to LaTex and programming

Comment: I also tried the imakeidx

Comment: In the `typeset` menu of TeXworks you can choose the second last entry in order to run makeindex. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L4nV.png

Comment: Select the last item in TeXworks `Typeset` menu and type `Ctrl + T`.

Comment: It has worked. Though in two columns, and I would have preferred one column. Thanks

Comment: With package `imakeidx` you can type a key-value optional argument: `\makeindex[columns=1]`.